# C++ Struct definition explanation

Tags: c++, struct

I read about defining a struct like:

```
struct someStruct {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct otherStruct : public someStruct {};
```

So my question is about the definition of otherStruct.
What does this definition do?
I'm new in C++ so i only want to know under which key word i can find the definition of otherStruct to read about them in a book.

Comment: [inheritance](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%2B%2B%20inheritance)

Comment: Are you asking how inheritance works? That's rather too large a subject for a simple answer, but your [introductory book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) should have a chapter about it.

Comment: @ChristinaObermaier [German] Guck dir mal das hier an... http://openbook.galileo-press.de/c_von_a_bis_z/ ist zwar C, aber davon kannst du C++ auch nach und nach lernen.

Comment: I only asked what this syntax part means. Now i know that otherStruct extends someStruct and that all i wanted to konw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is just a scratch on the surface of the `inheritance` concept of `OOP` and it does not cover all its aspects. You should read a book about `C++` (or about `OOP` in general) to get a complete answer.*

The part `struct otherStruct : public someStruct` says that `otherStruct` extends `someStruct` with `public` inheritance. In simple words, public inheritance does not change the visibility of the members (properties and methods) inherited from the base class.

The declaration block of the new struct (`{}`) is empty. It does not add any new members to those inherited from struct `someStruct`.

If you compare `someStruct` and `otherStruct` by their memory footprint and behaviour, they are identical. But they are different types and they cannot be replaced one for the other.

However, a pointer to a variable of type `otherStruct` can be used where a pointer to struct `someStruct` is expected (because `otherStruct`, by extending `someStruct` has all the properties expected from `someStruct`) but the other way around is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know what OOP is and its concepts. What i do not know is writing c++.. so i did not know what the syntax ment. Now i know that otherStruct extends someStruct. Thats all i wanted to know!